# How to add rotation effect when portrait to landscape

Tags: android

How to add rotation effect when change mode portrait to landscape ?

I want to make it smooth .

Please help me.

I want to sleep. T-T

Comment: -1: Me too, so I will just go to bed :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set android:configChanges="orientation" on your Activity and then implement onConfigurationChanged() on the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is handled by Android so you can't really change it without making your own custom ROM.